# Visual Force Page which can be accessed by anyone

Tags: visualforce, controller, url

I want to create a vf page which can be accessed by everyone whether he/she is the salesforce user or not (simply by URL) and want to collect information from that page into my custom object.Please guide me how I can get this functionality.

Comment: You can get this behavior with a community.

Comment: You can achieve this via salesforce Sites as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be using Force.com Sites. These let you create a publicly accessible sites using your Salesforce domain. You can then specify which Visualforce pages you want to be accessible to external users.

There is fairly comprehensive documentation available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites). To highlight a few key points:

- You first need to register a Domain name within Salesforce for your Site. You can do this under Setup | Develop | Sites.
- You can then create a Site as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites), making sure you set it to Active assuming you want people to be able to use it straight away.
- You then need to add your Visualforce Page to the list of assigned pages on the Site configuration page.
- You then need to ensure that external users have Read/Create access to the custom object in question. You can do this under Public Access Settings on the site page. **It is strongly recommend that you restrict access to the absolute minimum necessary to achieve the functionality you want.** You can achieve this by configuring field level security to limit the fields they can see/edit.

External users will then be able to go to your page by going to `yourdomain.my.salesforce.com/[VisualforcePageName]`.

As pointed out above it is also possible to achieve similar functionality using a Community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) for this purpose.

With `Sites` you can give authenticated/unauthenticated access to your `Visualforce Page` and save all the result you want with the controller into your `Custom Object`.