# Externally hosted Javascript is unable to access Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, integration, lightning-out, cors

From my Visualforce page I am calling an externally hosted Javascript app:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:iframe src="https://external.com/index.html" id="theFrame" />
</apex:page>
```

This external JS is trying to pull data from a Visualforce page located at:

```
fetch("https://mydomain.visualforce.com/apex/dataPage").then(...);
```

I added the external domain to my orgs CORS settings

[image]

The issue is the external script doesn't see the page and gets errors:

> Refused to connect to
> 'https://java-business-5237-dev-ed.cs69.my.salesforce.com/visualforce/session?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjava-business-5237-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com%2Fapex%dataPage'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "connect-src 'self' https://api.bluetail.salesforce.com
> https://staging.bluetail.salesforce.com
> https://preprod.bluetail.salesforce.com blob: *.visualforce.com
> https://java-business-5237-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com
> https://cs69.salesforce.com".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a Visualforce page from an external site unless you create a Salesforce site and access it.

See this answer for details:
[Visual Force Page which can be accessed by anyone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136978/visual-force-page-which-can-be-accessed-by-anyone)

Answer (score 3):

It seems, you need to add few of the domains in the whitelisted settings.

As per this [Allow the Required Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setup_domains.htm&type=5) :

> If you control your users’ or servers’ access to the Internet through
> allowlists, add these domains to ensure that you receive all
> Salesforce content.

- *.bluetail.salesforce.com
- *.content.force.com
- *.documentforce.com
- *.force.com
- *.forcesslreports.com
- *.forceusercontent.com
- *.lightning.com
- *.salesforce.com
- *.salesforceliveagent.com (used with Chat, Omni-Channel, and SOS)
- *.salesforce-communities.com (necessary if you’e using Communities or Site.com) trailblazer.me
- *.visualforce.com

Comment: Do I need to add them to CORS? Should I remove what’s already there? I’m confused as I expected the cors setting to be for the external site.

Comment: You need to add on top of that. I think req is traveling through different server internally to Salesforce.